# Как сделать прелодер изображения, сохраняющий пропорции оригинального файла?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Есть картинка-заглушка, выполняющая роль прелодера загружаемой картинки. Размеры загружаемой картинки известны и выведены в теге. Я так-же сделал у тега `img` `max-width:100%`, чтобы картинка не выходила за края страницы на маленьких экранах.

С оригинальной картинкой все работает хорошо, (чтобы сохранялись пропорции, я написал `height:auto`) Но когда ставим заглушку 1х1, пропорции картинки берутся соответственно 1 к 1, а не те, что указаны в теге. Если убрать `height:auto` ситуация все равно не решается, т.к. размер остается 200, а должен быть меньше.

```css
img{
  max-width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/1x1/03ded7/" width="1500" height="200">
```

Есть ли способ сделать здесь масштабирование с сохранением необходимых пропорций, не прибегая к JS?

Все картинки разных размеров, есть возможность что-то сделать при подстановке заглушек. Некоторые картинки меньше экрана, некоторые — больше. Кроме картинок ничего нет, вокруг теги `<p>` с текстом

Comment: ставится картинка или просто цвет какойто ?

Comment: Долго думал, может как-то и можно, но мне в голову ничего не приходит. Только с js есть возможность

Comment: @IvanKaraman просто цвет

Comment: напиши кусок html структурі, есть идея одна.

Comment: @IvanKaraman, написал в вопросе, кроме тега `img` ничего существенного нет. `img` лежит в `p`, `p` с картинками и текстами образуют длинную статью.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Решил задачу таким образом.**

Можно на лету создавать изображения в формате SVG того-же размера.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1500 200"   width="1500" height="200"/>
```

Полученный код закодировать и вставить в атрибут `src` изображения.

```
<img width="1500" height="200" src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns=%22http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%22%20viewBox=%220%200%201500%20200%22%20%20%20width=%221500%22%20height=%22200%22/%3E">
```

Пример реализации на JS:

```js
$('img').each(function() {

  //получаем размер изображения
  iw = $(this).attr('width')
  ih = $(this).attr('height')
    //Проверяем, есть ли размеры
  if (iw !== undefined && ih !== undefined) {
    //Создаем SVG с размерами изображения:
    svg = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 ' + iw + ' ' + ih + '"   width="' + iw + '" height="' + ih + '"/>';
    //Вставляем картинку прямо в тег:
    $(this).attr("src", "data:image/svg+xml," + encodeURI(svg));
  }

})
```

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background: #03ded7;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img width="1500" height="200">
```

Answer (score 3):

А что если через `background-image`, и `background-size:cover`

Comment: Вопрос в том как задать размеры html-элемента, а не как в уже заданных размерах разместить изображение. Так-то можно хоть `background-color` использовать.

Answer (score 2):

Если не менять код, а только заменять картинку, то через CSS нет способа это сделать. Картинки всё равно будут использовать пропорции подмены. Но если у вас картинки более-менее стандартного размера, то можно попробовать использовать не однопиксельную картинку, а картинку с теми же пропорциями.

Например, картинка в формате PNG с пропорциональными нужным вам размерами 15х2 пикселей имеет размер [лишь 95 байт](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOTuJ.png). Такую картинку лучше будет подключать по схеме `data:`, иначе вы на HTTP заголовки потратите больше. (Картинка полного размера занимает [лишь немного больше - 144 байта](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scAFI.png).)

Если же HTML код всё-таки можно поменять, то тут вариантов множество.

Comment: Вы почти дошли до того решения, что я придумал. Проблема в том, что картинки могут быть больше ширины экрана, а могут и меньше. Т.е. иногда картинки будут меньше 100%. Так-же картинки могут быть абсолютно любых размеров.

Comment: Не совсем честно вы действуете. В вопросе у вас написано что решить задачу нужно *не прибегая к JS*. Если бы можно было использовать JS, то и другие варианты есть!

Comment: JS тут для примера, замену картинок можно осуществить серверсайд. А вообще пишите, мне же надо кому-то 100 баллов отдать!